# why can not edit span after using jQuery Gridly plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make alignment of images with span using jQuery Gridly plugin. Its working fine what i expected. But my problem is, after using this plugin, I can not make span as editable.

Here is my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/72cr4bvk/21/

The code using to align,

```
 $('.gridly').gridly({
    columns: 8
    // base: 60, // px  
   //gutter: 20 // px
        });
    $('.gridly').gridly('draggable');
    return;
```

I hope someone will help me out!.

Comment: its because the parent elements are taking up the events and processing it. Try stopping the event propagation

Comment: @CerlinBoss can you please update code and share the link?

Comment: @CerlinBoss i dont know where i want to stop propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class name to the span, then using the class name remove the `click` and `mousedown` event

I have tried adding it on the `click me for align` btn but it was not working.

It works if i am adding using a `setTimeout`

Check this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Cerlin/72cr4bvk/25/)

So if you are able to get the proper click/mousedown event and suppress it then everything should work i guess.

**UPDATE**

I think i have solved the issue. There is some priority clash in jquery events it seems. Here i have used native `onmousedown` event

Code which i have added is:

```
var allspans = document.getElementsByClassName('insidespan');
$.each(allspans,function(index,value){
    allspans[index].onmousedown = function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/72cr4bvk/29/)

Comment: check now, inside span also editable but when click right click on that span.why?

Comment: remove the `dblclick` handler and see if that helps.

Comment: No!.i removed dblclick but not working!.but working when i click right click.